# ToggleButton setOnCheckedChangeListener on RecyclerView expandable item, gets called on the previously expanded item too

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, listener

On my `RecyclerView` `Adapter` I have this code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val isExpanded = position == expandedPosition
    holder.itemView.configurationLayout.visibility = if (isExpanded) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    holder.itemView.isActivated = isExpanded
    if (isExpanded) previousExpandedPosition = position

    holder.itemView.expandButton.setOnClickListener {
        expandedPosition = if (isExpanded) -1 else position
        notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition)
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    var item = items[position]
    holder.itemView.itemToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        item.toggleActive = isChecked
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the `ToggleButton` is `checked/unchecked` the `toggleActive` property is set on every item.

Edit:
I've seen that this problem is related to the ability to `expand/collapse` the items (which are `CardView` containers). I've made every item to be expanded always, and now the `ToggleButton` is working fine. Anyway, I need the items to collapse. I've updated my code above for you to see how I managed to expand and collapse the items.

Edit 2:
Now I can confirm that the `ToogleButton` listener is not called on every item, but only on the `current expanded item` and the `previous expanded item`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: i would suggest to save state of the togglebutton

Comment: The state of the ToggleButton is saved on SharedPreferences for every item.. if that's what you mean..

Comment: set the onchecked to null ..then create boolean variable in model class and setchecked for every items

Comment: Thanks AL for helping me, but I've done that already. I've made a change to my code, and I think I'm closer to what may be the cause of the problem. The items are CardViews and they can be expanded/collapsed. I've made every item to be always expanded, and now it works fine.. but I need the items to collapse. I'll update my question with some more relevant code

Comment: You can bind the position by a tag using to the holder.itemView.itemToggleButton.Tag(position) and then get that position in listener callback by  var status = buttonView.Tag and then change your items array and notify the adapter.

Comment: That sounds interesting Morya, I'll try it and let you know!

Comment: Sadly, using itemToggleButton.Tag(position) didn't worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this bug. The problem was related to the setOnCheckedChangeListener.

In my adapter, I was giving the ToggleButton.isChecked the value saved on SharedPreferences, and that was calling the listener. Changed it with setOnClickListener and now works perfect!